# If I send BTC from Jaxx will it give me both BTC and BCC

Tags: exchanges

Just want to know if Bittrex supports both blockchains, Bitcoin and Bitcoin cash, when importing from a Wallet like Jaxx

Comment: not exactly clear, what you mean by importing... Usually BitTRex provides an address, and you can send funds to this address. It works for BTC and BCC, I have tried them both in the past. There are many others as well. But importing? I don't think so, there is no link between your JAXX adress and the addresses/keys at BitTRex. Do you want to avoid the tx fees?

Comment: By importing I mean sending BTC to Bitrex from Jaxx.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin and bitcoin cash are two separate networks, if you send a tx on one network, it will not affect what happens on the other network. If you are using Jaxx, your wallet will show separate btc and bch balances in the app.

To deposit both btc and bch to Bittrex, you will not to get a btc deposit address from Bittrex and send btc to it. And then get a bch deposit address from Bittrex and send bch to it.

That said, I am unsure if Bittrex supports bch right now. If they do support it, the above will work. If they do not support bch, then obviously you cannot deposit a coin they do not support.

Comment: Thanks...I will look on Jaxx...The help  files on Bittrex says it supports the fork.

Comment: Chytrik is right: be careful not to mix btc/bcc. Only send bitcoin to bitcoin addresses, and bcc to bcc addresses. You cannot send across chains. This will make you lose your funds. Even if Jax supports both. And yes, bittrex supports both as well.